# Saving ~/.vnc/xstartup options for Xfce on VNC server

Tags: vnc

I'm following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04, added

~/.vnc/xstartup

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

And now I need to save it, though I see no option to save it. Any idea how can I save it?

Comment: Did you use nano as suggested in the tutorial? Press Ctrl+X, when prompted if you want to save it press Y, then Enter to confirm the file name.

Comment: BTW,  the `~/.vnc/xstartup` line in the tutorial is the file name, it is not supposed to be in the file. The first line in the file should be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @danzel yes, I'm using the nano.  cntrl-X brought me to save and exit option. Y didn't respond for a couple of times, but after a few times more it saved it. Thank you.

Comment: @danzel , it only looked like it saved it but didn't. after cntrl-X I can't choose Y. I'm Typing Y or y, but it doesn't save it, why?

Comment: You can explicitly save with Ctrl-O. Again, nano will ask you to confirm the file to write to (at the bottom of the terminal). Just press Enter. After saving, Ctrl-X will exit nano without any prompts.

Comment: If you have a qwertz keyboard layout, you can try Z instead of Y.

Comment: no, just press Enter.

Comment: Pressing Enter after Cntrl-O doesn't save it. It says:  [ Wrote 3 lines ], but when I recheck it I see a blank file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94443/discussion-between-danzel-and-niminim).

Comment: Ok, let's switch to chat.